# Javascript replace regex wildcard

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which I need to run a replace.

```
string = replace('/blogs/1/2/all-blogs/','');
```

The values 1, 2 and all-blogs can change. Is it possible to make them wildcards?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `.*` as a placeholder for "zero or more of any character here" or `.+` for "one or more of any character here". I'm not 100% sure exactly what you're trying to do, but for instance:

```
var str = "/blogs/1/2/all-blogs/";
str = str.replace(/\/blogs\/.+\/.+\/.+\//, '');
alert(str); // Alerts "", the string is now blank
```

But if there's more after or before it:

```
str = "foo/blogs/1/2/all-blogs/bar";
str = str.replace(/\/blogs\/.+\/.+\/.+\//, '');
alert(str); // Alerts "foobar"
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ucize3/2)

Note that in both of the above, only the *first* match will be replaced. If you wanted to replace *all* matches, add a `g` like this:

```
str = str.replace(/\/blogs\/.+\/.+\/.+\//g, '');
//                                       ^-- here
```

You can read up on JavaScript's [regular expressions on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: Might try using the lazy variant of the selector, namely `.*?` and `.+?` in cases where there might be additional slashes following the mentioned string.

Comment: @ShaneBishop - Thanks, I've fixed it. It's best, when things are so clear-cut like that, to just directly edit the change it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
js> 'www.google.de/blogs/1/2/all-blogs'.replace(/\/blogs\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/?/, '');
www.google.de
```

Comment: Does JS require `/` to be escaped?

Comment: As `/` is the delimiter for regexps (you don't put them in quotes): yes

Answer (score 1):

What about just splitting the string at slashes and just replacing the values?

```
var myURL = '/blogs/1/2/all-blogs/', fragments, newURL;
fragments = myURL.split('/');
fragments[1] = 3;
fragments[2] = 8;
fragments[3] = 'some-specific-blog';
newURL = fragments.join('/');
```

That should return:

```
'/blogs/3/8/some-specific-blog'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(/.+){4}
```

*escape as appropriate*

Comment: Better use `[^/]` instead of `.`.

Comment: @Gumbo that will hit the line returns though as well and that may not be what OP wants.